# LC3 Assembly Language with storage of values

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, lc3

I have to write a program that uses values stored in memory locations x4000 and x4001. How would I obtain the values stored within these two memory locations and put the values into registers?

I was thinking of loading the addresses into R1 and R2, and then maybe using the STR instruction. Ex.

Would this get the values within the memory locations x4000 and x4001 into R3 and R4?

Comment: The depends, are you planning on starting your main program from x3000 or much closer to x4000?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: `STR`, as its name says, STores not LoaDs. You will be better served by `LD` or `LDI`.